# Keep PyQt5 GUI Running while wating for another thread to finish

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5

I am trying keep a PyQt5 GUI running after a starting a function from a different file in a different thread, which works fine, and then wait for that thread to finsish to update some text on the GUI, which does not work fine.

File 1 (main.py):

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import  QMainWindow, QApplication,  QPushButton, QTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
import sys
from threading import Thread

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
  
        self.setWindowTitle("test")
        self.initWidgets()
        self.initWindow()

    def initWindow(self):
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 300, 300)
        self.show()
    
    def initWidgets(self):
        self.goButton = QPushButton("go", self)
        self.goButton.resize(100, 50)
        self.goButton.move(30, 30)
        self.goButton.setFont(QFont("Calibri", 11))
        self.goButton.clicked.connect(self.goButtonClicked)

        self.textBox = QTextEdit(self)
        self.textBox.resize(200, 40)
        self.textBox.move(30, 100)

        self.outBox = QTextEdit(self)
        self.outBox.resize(200, 40)
        self.outBox.move(30, 150)

       
    def goButtonClicked(self):
        self.var = self.textBox.toPlainText()
        from filewithfunc import testfunc
        self.thread1 = Thread(target=testfunc, args=(self.var,), daemon=False)
        self.thread1.start()
        self.thread2 = Thread(target=self.updateText)
        self.thread2.start()

    def updateText(self):
        self.thread1.join()
        from filewithfunc import capVar
        self.outBox.setText(capVar)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

File 2 (filewithfunc.py):

```
from time import sleep

def testfunc(var):
    sleep(5)
    global capVar
    capVar = var.capitalize()
```

Basically after pushing the button, the testfunc() function is called with variable from the textbox, and is then later displayed in the other textbox once the function finishes. I create a different thread for the both the testfunc() and updateText() function in hopes that it will keep the GUI from freezing, but I get this error:

```
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QTextDocument(0x1cb0c9aeff0), parent's thread is QThread(0x1cb0ca13cd0), current thread is QThread(0x1cb109b8310)
```

What can I do to remedy this. I read about using QThread, but I feel like that is slightly overkill and could just be done with threading, I might be wrong though.

Comment: If you need to interact with the UI, you *must* use QThread and signals. You cannot access UI elements from external threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out on my own, looks like QThread was definitely the way to go, quite easy to implement. Final code looks like this.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import  QMainWindow, QApplication,  QPushButton, QTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont

import sys
from threading import Thread

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):

        Window.var = "t"

        super().__init__()
  
        self.setWindowTitle("test")
        self.initWidgets()
        self.initWindow()

    def initWindow(self):
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 300, 300)
        self.show()
    
    def initWidgets(self):
        self.goButton = QPushButton("go", self)
        self.goButton.resize(100, 50)
        self.goButton.move(30, 30)
        self.goButton.setFont(QFont("Calibri", 11))
        self.goButton.clicked.connect(self.goButtonClicked)

        self.textBox = QTextEdit(self)
        self.textBox.resize(200, 40)
        self.textBox.move(30, 100)

        self.outBox = QTextEdit(self)
        self.outBox.resize(200, 40)
        self.outBox.move(30, 150)

       
    def goButtonClicked(self):
        Window.var = self.textBox.toPlainText()
        self.worker = workerThread()
        self.worker.start()
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.updateText)
        

    def updateText(self):
        from filewithfunc import capVar
        self.outBox.setText(capVar)


class workerThread(QThread):
    def run(self):
        from filewithfunc import testfunc
        self.funcThread = Thread(target=testfunc, args=(Window.var,), daemon=True)
        self.funcThread.start()
        print("sat")
        self.funcThread.join()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Basically when goButton is clicked, a worked thread is started which imports and calls the function from the other file, then waits for it to finish before updating the text on the screen.

Comment: This solution is a bit daft. You *do not* need to create a python thread as well. Just call `testfunc` directly inside `run`. If you need to forward arguments, pass them in the `__init__` of the worker thread (so you can do e.g. `testfunc(self._args)`).